# Simple Question: How do I use tidyr::contains to act as an AND statement instead of an OR statement?

Tags: r

I am trying to pivot a dataframe using `contains()` based on column names that contain two different phrases.  However, every time I nest a vector within `contains()`, it returns it as an either-or expression and I want it to return the columns that contain *both* "name1" and "name2".

```
df <- data.frame(dogs_cats_eagles = c(1,2,3), dogs_cats_wolves = c(1,2,3), dogs_bears_wolves = c(1,2,3), eagles_bears_wolves = c(1,2,3))

df %>%
         pivot_longer(cols = contains(c("dogs", "wolves")), names_to = 'type')
```

I want it to return:

```
   type                value
   <chr>               <dbl>
 1 dogs_cats_wolves        1
 2 dogs_bears_wolves       1
 3 dogs_cats_wolves        2
 4 dogs_bears_wolves       2
 5 dogs_cats_wolves        3
 6 dogs_bears_wolves       3
```

Thank you!

Comment: Try using `matches("dogs|wolves")`

Comment: @LMc Seems like OP has OR already and wants AND

Comment: You can do `cols = contains("dogs") & contains("wolves")`

Comment: Thank you!  I knew it'd be simple like this but couldn't think of it.